# jQuery Form Validation Assign Submit Button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-validate

So, I have a form and 2 buttons, 1 button is only for verifying email, meanwhile the other button is the form submit button. I'm using jQuery validation to validate the form.

What I want is it should only the **SUBMIT** button that can submit the form through `submitHandler` and execute `alert("success")`, but whenever I click the **VERIFY** button, it also submit the form through `submitHandler` and execute `alert("success")`.

Here is the script:

`index.html`:

```
<form id="form_data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input id="phone_number" name="phone_number" required>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-9">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <button id="btn_email">VERIFY</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="form_data_submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

`script.js`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var btnSubmitEl = $("#form_data_submit");
    var formEl = $("#form_data");

    formEl.validate({ // initialize jquery validation plugin
        rules: {
            phone_number: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 7,
                maxlength: 12
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7,
                maxlength: 20
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            alert("success")
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should explicitly set `type=”button"` for the verify button as you're using HTML5.
Default button behaviour submits the form.
Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10836076)

Comment: At first, I thought that this is a problem specific to jQuery validation library. It turns out that in HTML5 a `<button>` tag is actually a "submit" button by default.` Wow, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You don't need 2 buttons to validate the form you could validate the form and submit using only one button, if for whatever reason you want to use 2 buttons you have to use 2 event listeners one for the validate button and one for the submit button, and the reason why your validate button submits the form it's because the `formEl.validate` takes an object, inside that object there is a function called `submitHandler` it submits the form after it's verified so you have to set it to return false.
I have implemented this in the code bellow

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var btnSubmitEl = $("#form_data_submit");
    var formEl = $("#form_data");
    var verifybtn=$("#btn_email");
    btnSubmitEl.on("click",()=>{
       formEl.submit()//
         alert("success")

    })
    verifybtn.on("click",()=>{
    formEl.validate({ // initialize jquery validation plugin
        rules: {
            phone_number: {
                required: true,
                number: true,
                minlength: 7,
                maxlength: 12
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 7,
                maxlength: 20
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function () {
            return false;
        }
    });
});
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form_data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Phone Number</label>
        <input id="phone_number" name="phone_number" required>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-9">
            <label>Email</label>
            <input id="email" name="email" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-3">
            <button id="btn_email">VERIFY</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button id="form_data_submit" type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.2/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```